# Can't open Adblock page from within Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to allow users to add an Adblock Whitelist via a Chrome extension. To allow this there is the API like such:

```
<a href="abp:subscribe?location=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ebates.com%2Fwhitelist%2Febates-cash-back-shopping.txt&amp;title=Cash%20Back%20Shopping">1) Add The Ebates WhiteList</a>
```

However if I add that link to a Chrome extension popup window the link doesn't go anywhere. My guess is that the Chrome extension execution context isn't aware of Adblock/able to support that API. Is anyone who is more of an extension wizard than myself able to verify that I'm correct in my assumption and that there is no workaround? Thanks!

Comment: Try chrome.tabs.create({url: '.......'}) in onclick handler for the link.

Comment: @wOxxOm Good suggestion, I had similar code lined up for navigating to Chrome internal settings but it doesn't work in this case.

Comment: Evidently this link is handled by ABP's content script so you'll have to add it into a web page.

Comment: See also their documentation, maybe they provide an API for this case.

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks for your help, so it looks like the popup occurs within its own Chrome context and doesn't have access to the AB content script right? And honestly it's not a big deal for me to just direct to a page in the browser so I don't need to dig into the API really

Comment: Yep, the popup is a separate window with chrome-extension:// URL.

Comment: @wOxxOm If you want to add that as an answer I'm happy to accept it